# GWT - Implementing Cut, Copy & Paste in a page having 70 odd widgets

Tags: javascript, gwt, user-interface, focus, copy-paste

I am trying to implement the cut, copy and paste functionality for a
page that has around 70 widgets including text boxes, list boxes,
labels, containers, panels and so on. The cut, copy and paste buttons
are part of these. When a User selects text in some text box in the
page and clicks on copy, the text box loses focus and the copy button
now has it. I need the text to call a method that has some Javascript
call in it like:

$wnd.window.clipboardData.setData("Text",text);

In order for me to do that I need text from the text box and because
the copy button now has it, I do not know where it has been selected
from.

Can anyone let me know if they have done anything similar before using
GWT?

Comment: I think you mean `$wnd.clipboardData` not `$wnd.window.clipboardData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late but finally I am posting how i worked around this issue last year itself.

I created MouseOverHandlers for the cut, copy and paste buttons and when the User hovers over any of those widgets, in the handling logic I am using some native javaScript code to find the active element in DOM and am converting it to a GWT element using GQuery.

After converting it, I check if it is an instance of TextBoxBase and if it is, I just pick up the text from that field to cut, copy. Paste works similarly except I paste only when the widget is an instance of TextBoxBase (so that TextBox and TextArea widgets are covered.)

Answer (score 1):

I think GWT doesn't support copy & paste. But you could implement the copy/paste operation using [JSNI Methods](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

In order to know which textbox was used for the copy/paste operation you could add a [FocusHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/FocusHandler.html) or a [BlurHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/BlurHandler.html) to all textboxes, which can store the last textbox which was focused/blurred.

```
public class CopyPasteExample {
      private TextBox lastTextBox = null;

      private class CopyPasteFocusHandler implements FocusHandler {

             @Override
             public void onFocus(FocusEvent ev) {
                    lastTextBox = (TextBox) ev.getSource();
             }

      }

      private native void copy (String s) /*-{
             $wnd.window.clipboardData.setData("Text", s); 
      }-*/;

      private void copyFromLastTextBox() {
             if (lastTextBox != null) {
                 copy(lastTextBox.getValue());
             }
      }

}
```